# disregard line breaks in field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to import data into my MS SQL DB (as a flat file). However, there  is a problem with one of the fields: it contains a line break within the data, which leads to the import wizard thinking it's the end-of-line, hence breaking each row into two. I've tried to import the data into excel as well (just to try it out), but it's the same behavior.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Any pre-import mechanism that might massage the data somehow?

(unfortunately, it's not practically possible for me to ask the source system to change the encoding)

//Eva-Lotta

Comment: Is your row delimiter also a line break? If so, are your columns text identified? If the answer are yes, and no (respectively) then there's little you can do with the data as is. You'll either need to text identify your data, or introduce a new row delimiter. (Effectively the problem is at the extract point, not the import, and you need to fix the extract process.)

Comment: what does "text identify" men? it's a flat, pipe-separated file with the fields also are enclosed within semi-colons. And yes, I'd for sure prefer if the source system could fix this when they generate the raw data ...

Comment: One method of text identification is quotes. Take, for example this "3"  column comma separated data: `1,Mr Smith,123 The Street, AB12 1AB`. It looks like looks like 4 columns, as the address has a comma. if there data is text identified it looks like this: `1, Mr Smith,"123 The Street, AB12 1AB"`. Notice the quotes around the address. If your data contains a delimiter within the text, you either need to text identify your data, or change your delimiter.

Comment: Ah, I see. When looking into the data, it has both | as delimiter and "" surrounding the contents. Still, I get a linebreak in the middle of a field. I think I have to make another try to get the source system to produce sound data ...

Comment: We need to know more about your import process then. Detail the process you're using to import the data. Are you defining you're text identier in your ETL process?

Comment: I've just gotten raw files that I need to analyze, with limited information about how they are defined (i.e. I'm not involved in how they are produced). At this stage, I'm just doing the analysis of their contents, meaning that I can place requirements towards the source system on things like line-breaks once the analysis is done. However, it's actually a rather common (still annoying) problem that we are provided with files with line-breaks within fields, and I'd love to find a reusable / generic solution.

Comment: @Eva-Lotta tell whoever produces those files to use *text delimiters*, eg double quotes. Or tell them to use some other character as a line delimiter, eg § or ¶. You'll have to do that if the flat files can contain quotes or double quotes in note fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use to replace new line character in columns having values.

```
Replace(Replace(columnName,char(13),' '),char(10),' ')
```

Regards

Comment: Risking to sound really stupid, but where should I use this code?

Comment: How would this work against a flat file, and how would you know what is a row delimiter and what isn't?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a work-around! I start with splitting the files into chunks (as they are 3.8 GB in size ...), open them in UltraEdit, loop through them to join the 2 lines together, and import them into excel / my SQL DB. It's not neat, but it has solved my immediate problem ... but thanks for your engagement!

Comment: A better solution would be to tell whoever produces those files to use a different character as a line ending. No need to edit the files. Even if they come eg from AS400 or DB2 it's possible to specify a custom field or line separator.